# How to set Navigation Drawer opened from right when click on navigation view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to  set Navigation Drawer opened from right when click on nav_language ... this is to change language of navigation drawer to arabic, i'm also want to set navigation drawer to right

```
else if (id==R.id.nav_language)
    {
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem nav_language = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_language);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        //preferences.edit().putString("lang", "bn").commit();

        String lang = preferences.getString("lang", "en");
        //Log.e("lang", "lang in Main Activity:"+lang);
        if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase("en"))
        {
            setLocale("ar");
            preferences.edit().putString("lang", "ar").commit();
            nav_language.setTitle("الانجليزية");
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        } else if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase("ar")) {
            setLocale("en");
            preferences.edit().putString("lang", "en").commit();
            nav_language.setTitle("Arabic");
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        }
private void setLocale(String lang) {
  Locale  myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, HomePageActivity.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Did you add tools:openDrawer="right" to the DrawerLayout in .XML file?
Also DrawerLayout Class has two methods openDrawer(gravity) and closeDrawer(gravity)
where you can pass them gravity as Gravity.RIGHT

Answer (score 0):

You must add this in your xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="right"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I mean `openDrawer="right"` for the drawer layout and `android:layout_gravity="right"` for the navigation_view ,In any case, using the menu on the right is not recommended, I wish that helps.

Comment: I don't want default of navigation drawer to be right.. I wanna be Right when click on item in the menu that has I'd " nav_lang"